# Appium error when trying to run an automated script to launch app on actual device

Tags: android, appium

Friends,
Below is the appium error log: can you please help me resolve this

## I am running as a junit ,should i run as testng/android app?

## AndroidMainfest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.demo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

## .java file:

```
package demolaunchtest;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class helloTest {
public static AndroidDriver driver;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {

File appDir = new File ("Computer\\Lokesh Gangaiah\\Phone\\Download");
File app = new File (appDir,"selendroid-test-app-0.17.0.apk");

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "");
        //capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");

        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Lokesh Gangaiah");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0");
        capabilities.setCapability("device", "Android");

        capabilities.setCapability("app",app.getAbsolutePath());
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "io.selendroid.testapp");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "io.selendroid.testapp.HomeScreenActivity");

        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

@Test
public void test() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    // fail("Not yet implemented");
}
```

}

=

> info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
>   error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was:    Error:      hasInternetPermissionFromManifest failed. Error: Command failed:    C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe     /s /c "C:\Users\GangaiahL\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe dump badging "
>      ERROR: no dump file specified
>
> info: [debug] Error: hasInternetPermissionFromManifest failed.     Error:   Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "C:\Users\GangaiahL\AppData\Local\Android    \sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe dump badging "
>   ERROR: no dump file specified
>
> ```
> at C:\Program  Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:1664:19
> at     ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:758:5)
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
>    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1016:16)
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit     (child_process.js:1088:5)
> ```
>
> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":     {"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: hasInternetPermissionFromManifest    failed. Error: Command failed:    C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c \"C:\Users\GangaiahL\  \AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe dump badging    \"\nERROR: no dump file      specified\r\n)","origValue":"hasInternetPermissionFromManifest failed. Error:   Command failed: C:\   \Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c   \"C:\Users\GangaiahL\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-    tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe dump badging \"\nERROR: no dump file   specified\r\n"},"sessionId":null}
>      info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 568.702 ms - 594

## NEW ERROR:

> info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: hasInternetPermissionFromManifest failed. Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c \"C:\Users\GangaiahL\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe dump badging \"\nERROR: no dump file specified\r\n)","origValue":"hasInternetPermissionFromManifest failed. Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c \"C:\Users\GangaiahL\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe dump badging \"\nERROR: no dump file specified\r\n"},"sessionId":null}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 566.022 ms - 594

Comment: Can you please share code snippet for code to launch app on actual device

Comment: Error: hasInternetPermissionFromManifest failed -- This says app doesn't have internet permission. Enable this.

Comment: @DarshanAmbhaikar pls see the shared .java file

Comment: @PankajKatiyar can u pls tell me how to enable this?

Comment: Does your manifest.xml has internet permission set??                     <manifest xlmns:android...>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application ...
</manifest>

Comment: pls see mainfest.xml file added in above comment....@PankajKatiyar have the permission added,but still not working

Comment: @PankajKatiyar, Yes after changing my code the problem with " 
Error: hasInternetPermissionFromManifest failed -- " has solved, but there is another error seen ---- >

Comment: @PankajKatiyar updated my new code above,now pls have a look at it. I am specifying my app path to my mobile directory where the .apk is residing ,is it correct?

Comment: @Lokesh : Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
##Error 1:

    By seeing your java code, I see this line is the problem:
    capabilities.setCapability("app","app.getAbsolutePath()");

    If app is a variable then it should be without quotes like:
    capabilities.setCapability("app",app.getAbsolutePath());

    Because of this appium can't find the app file to dump.


## Error 2:

Change these:

   File appDir = new File ("Computer\\Lokesh Gangaiah\\Phone\\Download");
   File app = new File (appDir,"selendroid-test-app-0.17.0.apk");

to:
   File app = new File ("Computer\\Lokesh Gangaiah\\Phone\\Download\\selendroid-test-app-0.17.0.apk");

And make sure you have apk file at this location.
```